# Update row by given value in hidden datatable column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a data table (using jquery plugin datatable) with a hidden column that stores unique id's for each row.
i am trying to write a function that given a row id and data - updates the corresponding row with the given data.

what is the best way to go about here ?
should i iterate all table data or is there a better way ?

this is what i tried (not sure if is the correct approach):

```
function updateById(data){           
  var tableData = $('#example').dataTable();
  var rowNum = tableData.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
  for(var i=0;i<rowNum;i++)
  {
      if(tableData.fnGetData(i,5) === data.id){
      console.log("Found at "+i);
      tableData.fnUpdate(data.status,i,INDEX_STAT);
  }
}
```

Comment: That depends how your data looks like and how you initialise the dataTable. Please show some code demonstrating whar you are trying to do.

Comment: @davidkonrad added code to demonstrate my intent.